# JS methods does not load in onload method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `HTML` file, with some `Script` inside.
I bring all `functions` in one `Script` Tag.
Now I want to use these methods in `onload` and `onclick` events.
Here is this HTML file with all scripts :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">

        </script>      
        <script src="../configwireless.php">

        </script>
        <title>configuration</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>    
            .center {
                margin: auto;
                width: 40%;
                border: 3px solid #73AD21;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background : url(wall5.jpg) center no-repeat;       
            }
            @font-face { 
                font-family: myFont;
                src: url(fonts/Raleway-Medium.otf);
                src: url(fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf);
                src: url(fonts/Raleway-Medium.woff); 

            }
            body { 
                font-family:myFont;
                background : url(wall5.jpg) center;
                height: 100%;
                font-family:myFont;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                width: 100%;
            }  
            lable { 
                font-family:myFont;
            }
            form{
                font-family: myFont;


            }
            input {
                text-align: center;
            }


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form  name="general" action="" id="general" class="center" method="post"> 

            <div id="wirelessmodediv">
                <label>Wireless Mode</label>
                <select name="wirelessmode" id="wirelessmode" 
                        onclick="checkGeneralWirelessMode()">
                    <option value="ap">AP</option>
                    <option value="xxx">Client</option>
                    <option value="xxx">Client Bridge(Routed)</option>
                    <option value="xxx">Adhoc</option>
                    <option value="xxx">WDS Station</option>
                    <option value="xxx">WDS AP</option>   
                </select> <br>
            </div>
            <div id="networkmodediv">
                <label>Wireless Network Mode</label>  
                <select name="wirelessNetworkMode" id="wirelessNetworkMode">
                    <option value="disabled">Disable</option>
                    <option value="mixed">Mixed</option>
                    <option value="a-only">A-Only</option>
                    <option value="na-only">NA-Mixed</option>
                    <option value="n5-only">N-Only(5 GHz)</option>  
                </select> <br>
            </div>

            <div id="channelwidthdiv" >
                <label> Channel Width </label>

                <select id="channelWidth" name="channelWidth">  
                    <option value="20">Full</option>
                    <option value="40">Wide </option>
                    <option value="2040">Dynamic </option>
                    <option value="10">Half (10 MHz)</option>
                    <option value="5">Quarter(5 MHz)</option>
                </select> <br> 
            </div>
            <div id="countrydiv">
                <label>Country</label>           
                <select id="country" name="country" 
                        onchange="fillWirelessChannel();"
                        onload="fillWirelessChannel();"
                        onclick="fillWirelessChannel();">
                    <option value="china"  >China</option>
                    <option value="japan"  >japan</option>
                </select> 
            </div>                                                
            <br>
            <div id="wirelesschannel">
                <label>Wireless Channel</label> 

                <select id="wirelessChannel" name="wirelessChannel">

                </select> 
            </div> 
            <br>   

            <div id="extentionchanneldiv">
                <label> Extention Channel </label>

                <select id="extentionChannel" name="extentionChannel">
                    <option value="auto">auto</option>
                    <option value="lower">lower</option>
                    <option value="upper">upper</option>
                </select> 
            </div>
            <br> 
            <div id="linkname" >
                <label>Wireless Link Name</label>   

                <input type="text" name="ssid" id="ssid" /><br>  
            </div>

            <div id="ssidbroadcast" >
                <label>Wireless SSID Broadcast</label> 

                <input type="radio" name="broadcaststatus" id="enablebroadcaststatus" 
                       value="0"> Enable
                <input type="radio" name="broadcaststatus" id="disablebroadcaststatus" value="1" > Disable <br>
            </div>         
            <div id="gatewaydiv" >
                <label>Default GW Mode</label>   

                <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="1" onclick="checkDefaultGateway()"> Auto (DHCP) 
                <input type="radio" name="gateway" id="gateway" value="0" onclick="checkDefaultGateway()"> Manual <br> 
            </div>


            <div id="gatewayipdiv" >
                <label>Gateway</label> 
                <input type="text" name="gatewayip" id="gatewayip" ><br>  
            </div>   


            <label>Advanced Setting</label>           

            <input type="checkbox" name="advancecheck" id="advancecheck" 
                   onchange="advancecheckChanged()" 
                   onload="advancecheckChanged()"/><br>



            <div id="advanceddiv" style="display:none;">

                <label>Super Channel</label>   

                <input type="radio" name="supperchannel" value="ebable"> Enable 
                <input type="radio" name="supperchannel" value="disable"> Disable <br>     
                <label>TX Power</label>         

                <input type="text" name="txpower" id="txpower"><br>
                <label>Antenna Gain</label>         

                <input type="text" name="antennagain" id="antennagain"><br>  

                <label>Noise Immunity</label>   

                <input type="radio" name="noise" id="enablenoise" value="1"> Enable 
                <input type="radio" name="noise" id="disablenoise" value="0"> Disable <br> 
                <label> Protection Mode </label>

                <select id="protection">
                    <option value="None">one</option>
                    <option value="CTS">CTS</option>
                    <option value="RTS/CTS">RTS/CTS</option>
                </select> <br> 
                <label>RTS Threshold</label>  

                <input type="text" name="rts" id="rts">  <br>  
                <label>Short Preamble</label>  

                <input type="radio" name="preamble" id="enablepreamble" value="ebable"> Enable 
                <input type="radio" name="preamble" id="disablepreamble" value="disable"> Disable <br>   
                <label>Short GI</label>  

                <input type="radio" name="gi" id="enablegi" value="1"> Enable 
                <input type="radio" name="gi" id="disablegi" value="0"> Disable <br>   
                <label>TX Antenna Chains</label>

                <select id="txantennachains">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="3">1+2</option>

                </select><br>
                <label>RX Antenna Chains</label>

                <select id="rxantennachains">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="3">1+2</option>

                </select><br>    
                <label>Beacon Interval</label>      
                <input type="text" name="interval" id="interval"><br>

                <label>DTIM Interval</label>                           
                <input type="text" name="dtiminterval" id="dtiminterval"><br>
                <label>AP Isolation</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="isolation" id="enableisolation" value="1"> Enable 
                <input type="radio" name="isolation" id="disableisolation" value="0"> Disable <br>   

                <label>Sensitivity Range (ACK Timing)</label>   

                <input type="text" name="sensitiverange" id="sensitiverange"><br>                     
                <label>Max Associated Clients</label>   

                <input type="text" name="maxassociate" id="maxassociate"><br>  
                <label>Network Configuration</label> 
                <input type="radio" name="configuration" id="enableconfiguration" value="0"
                       onload="checkBridgeMode()"
                       onclick="checkBridgeMode()"
                       onchange="checkBridgeMode()"> Unbridge 
                <input type="radio" name="configuration" id="disableconfiguration" value="1" 
                       onload="checkBridgeMode()"
                       onclick="checkBridgeMode()"
                       onchange="checkBridgeMode()"> Bridge<br>  

                <div id="multicastdiv">
                    <label>Multicast forwarding</label> 

                    <input type="radio" name="multicast" id="enablemulticast" value="1"> Enable 
                    <input type="radio" name="multicast" id="disablemulticast" value="0"> Disable <br>    

                    <label>Masquerade / NAT</label> 

                    <input type="radio" name="masquerade" id="enablemasquerade" value="1"> Enable 
                    <input type="radio" name="masquerade" id="disablemasquerade" value="0"> Disable <br>

                    <label>Net Isolation</label> 

                    <input type="radio" name="netisolation" id="enablenetisolation" value="1"> Enable 
                    <input type="radio" name="netisolation" id="disablenetisolation" value="0"> Disable <br>

                    <label>Forced DNS Redirection</label> 


                    <input type="radio" name="forcedns" id="enableforcedns" value="1" 
                           onload="Checkradiobutton()" onclick="Checkradiobutton()" > Enable 
                    <input type="radio" name="forcedns" id="disableforcedns" value="0" 
                           onload="Checkradiobutton()" onclick="Checkradiobutton()"> Disable <br> 


                    <label>Optional DNS Target</label>   

                    <input type="text" name="optionaldns" id="optionaldns"><br> 
                    <label>IP Address</label>   

                    <input type="text" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress"><br> 
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="subnetmaskdiv" style="display:none;">
                <label>Subnet Mask</label>
                <input type="text" name="subnetmask" id="subnetmask"><br>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="apply" id="apply" value="Apply"/>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function checkGeneralWirelessMode() {

                if ((document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "ap") ||
                        (document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "infra") ||
                        (document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "wdsap"))
                {

                    document.getElementById("channelwidthdiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("countrydiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("extentionchanneldiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("wirelesschannel").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("linkname").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("ssidbroadcast").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("networkmodediv").style.display = 'block';

                    document.getElementById("gatewayipdiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("gatewaydiv").style.display = 'none';

                } else if (document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "wet") {

                    document.getElementById("networkmodediv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("gatewayipdiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("linkname").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("gatewaydiv").style.display = 'block';

                    document.getElementById("extentionchanneldiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("channelwidthdiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("countrydiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("wirelesschannel").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("ssidbroadcast").style.display = 'none';

                } else if (document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "sta" ||
                        document.getElementById('wirelessmode').value == "wdssta") {

                    document.getElementById("channelwidthdiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("linkname").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("networkmodediv").style.display = 'block';

                    document.getElementById("extentionchanneldiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("gatewayipdiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("gatewaydiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("countrydiv").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("wirelesschannel").style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById("ssidbroadcast").style.display = 'none';
                }

            }

            function advancecheckChanged() {
                if (document.getElementById('advancecheck').checked &&
                        document.getElementById('enableforcedns').checked) {

                    document.getElementById("advanceddiv").style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'block';
                } else
                    document.getElementById("advanceddiv").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'none';

            }
            function fillWirelessChannel() {
                var index;
                var selectTag = document.getElementById('wirelessChannel');
                selectTag.options.length = 0;
                var auto = document.createElement("option");
                auto.value = 'auto';
                auto.innerHTML = 'auto';
                selectTag.appendChild(auto);
//                    console.log(document.getElementById('country').value);

                if (document.getElementById('country').value == "iran") {
                    for (index = 4920; index <= 5825; index += 5) {
                        var opt = document.createElement("option");
                        opt.value = index;
                        opt.innerHTML = index;
                        selectTag.appendChild(opt);
                    }
                } else if (document.getElementById('country').value == "japan") {
                    for (index = 4920; index <= 6075; index += 5) {
                        var otherOpt = document.createElement("option");
                        otherOpt.value = index;
                        otherOpt.innerHTML = index;
                        selectTag.appendChild(otherOpt);
                    }
                }
            }

            function checkDefaultGateway() {
                if (document.getElementById('gateway').checked) {
                    document.getElementById("gatewayipdiv").style.display = 'none';
                } else
                    document.getElementById("gatewayipdiv").style.display = 'block';

            }

            function checkBridgeMode() {
                if (document.getElementById('enableconfiguration').checked) {
                    document.getElementById("multicastdiv").style.display = 'block';
                } else
                    document.getElementById("multicastdiv").style.display = 'none';
            }

            function Checkradiobutton() {
                if (document.getElementById('enableforcedns').checked) {
                    document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'block';
                } else
                    document.getElementById("subnetmaskdiv").style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script> 
    </body>

</html>
```

I can call methods in `onclick` event via using `onclick` method in every tag I want use a specific method.
But I want to try all methods in `onload`.
I tried `onload="functionName;"` in tags, but no effect.
I used `window.onload="functionName";` in end of the script tags, but no effect.
I just could use

```
window.onload=function somefuntion() {
```

in function declaration and in worked.
But just for one method I can do that and when I do in this way the `onclick` method does not work.
How can I use these methods in `onload` and in `onclick` both? in my satisfied tags?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I don't understand it.

Comment: `window.onload=function somefuntion() ` replaces the onload function.   As you've tagged this `jquery`, use `$(function() { ..code for onload ... });`

Comment: @StuntHacks : In JS methods I hide some elements, depends on what are the default values are and after that what end-user select.
I also fill some elements in JS functions.
I want to effect these JS in onload method

Comment: @freedomn-m : Could you post your answer so I can try that?
I want to use that as onclick method too.
Your code works in onload, but how can I use this in onclick method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
  someFunc1();
  someFunc2();
},false);
```

Comment: at the end of my script before </script> I can use this?

Comment: Yup, this can be used everywhere.

Comment: Let me try this for a sec.

Comment: Thanks sir,Could you take a look at this question too?
Im brand new to PHP and all dependencies !
Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243515/html-form-display-the-first-options-and-empty-inputs-after-submit

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in PHP and jquery, but still, hope you'll find your answer here.